# How to debug a SSH socks tunnel connection?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, socks, tunnel

I followed this guide https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-route-web-traffic-securely-without-a-vpn-using-a-socks-tunnel on how to set up a VPS connection to Windows.

And my tunnel connection is running on Windows fine, Putty connects no problem, but when I add settings to my Firefox to use proxy, 127.0.0.1/localhost etc it simply does not load any page, it just doesn't work.

I also tested with [MyEntunnel](https://github.com/feralhosting/feralfilehosting/tree/master/Feral%20Wiki/SSH/SSH%20tunnels%20-%20MyEnTunnel), and it reports the connection to tunnel is stable and gives green light. But proxy settings do not work in any application.

My Windows firewall is disabled.

Where do I look at first, to track down the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should tell firefox tu use a **Socks Proxy**, not http nor https when you are using a dynamic port-forwarding (`-D`) port with ssh.

Example:
if you connect with `ssh -D 1080 user@example.com`, you will need to configure Firefox to use socks proxy on server `localhost`, port `1080`.

Also, note that [FoxyProxy](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/foxyproxy-standard/) is very useful Firefox extension for those who need to switch proxies often.